# Simplifying boolean expression to minimum CNF

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

I have the boolean expression,

$$(a\not\to b)\lor(c\not\to d)\lor(a\not\to d)\lor(b\not\to d)$$

Can I simplify this to,

$$ (a \vee c \vee b ) \wedge (a \vee \neg d) \wedge (\neg b \vee \neg d) $$

I am trying to create the minimum CNF.

Comment: Do you know [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), or you want to prove it with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)?

Comment: Possibly I could simplify it to, $$ (a \vee c \vee b )\wedge (a \vee \neg b \vee \neg d) $$ ?

Comment: Not really, take $a\equiv\bot,b\equiv\bot,c\equiv\top,d\equiv\top$ have $(a∨c∨b)∧(a∨¬b∨¬d)\equiv\top$ and $(a∨c∨b)∧(c∨a)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)\equiv \bot$, which is counter example.

Comment: I have also used a Karnaugh map to solve it although I got a different result. I should note that the question does not show the original expression. The original expression is, $$(a{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}b) \vee (c{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}d)\vee (a{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}d) \vee (b{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}d)$$

Comment: That not equivalent to your expression $(a∨c∨b)∧(c∨a)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)$, that's why you got a different result, take $a\equiv\bot,b\equiv\top,c\equiv\bot,d\equiv\bot$ gives $(a∨c∨b)∧(c∨a)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)\equiv\bot$ but your $(a\not⟹b)∨(c\not⟹d)∨(a\not⟹d)∨(b\not⟹d)$ $\equiv\top$

Comment: Oh, I must have simplified it incorrectly. When I found it using the Karnuagh map I got the result, $$ (a \vee b \vee c )\wedge (a \vee b \vee \neg d) \wedge (\neg b \vee c \vee \neg d) $$ Is that the correct result?

Comment: $(a∨c∨b)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)$, is the minimum CNF of $(a\not\to b)\lor(c\not\to d)\lor(a\not\to d)\lor(b\not\to d)$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The CNF I found using a Karnaugh map for the expression (⧸⟹)∨(⧸⟹)∨(⧸⟹)∨(⧸⟹) was (∨∨)∧(∨∨¬)∧(¬∨∨¬). I do not know if it is correct though.

Comment: Not correct, take $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv d\equiv \top$, this gives $(∨∨)∧(∨∨¬)∧(¬∨∨¬)\equiv\top$ but $(a\not\to b)∨(c\not\to d)∨(a\not\to d)∨(b\not\to d)\equiv \bot$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the CNF result I got from the Karnaugh map was, $$ (a \vee b \vee c )\wedge (a \vee \neg d) \wedge (\neg b \vee \neg d) $$. I think this is the minimum CNF although I am not sure how to get to this result using boolean algebra.

Comment: Correct, this is the Karnaugh map for $(a\not\to b)∨(c\not\to d)∨(a\not\to d)∨(b\not\to d)$:

$$\boxed{
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&a'b'&a'b&ab&ab'\\
c'd'&0&1&1&1\\
c'd&0&0&0&1\\
cd&0&0&0&1\\
cd'&1&1&1&1
\end{array}}$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I got. Thanks! If you can add an answer showing how to simplify the expression to that using boolean algebra I will accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited the question so the answer will make sense.

Comment: See the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The statement $(a∨c∨b)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)$ not equivalent to:$$(a∨c∨b)∧(c∨a)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)$$For the minimum CNF, you can draw a k-map, but use Logical equivalence is actually easier in this case, the idea is use Absorption law on $(a \lor c)\land(a\lor c\lor b)$.

**Answer:**

> \begin{align}&(a∨c∨b)∧(c∨a)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)\\\equiv&(a∨c)∧(a∨c∨b)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)\tag*{Commutative law}\\\equiv&(a∨c)∧(a∨¬d)∧(¬b∨¬d)\tag*{Absorption law}\\\end{align}

---

Update:

**Hint:**

Use Logical equivalence to find minimum CNF for $(a\not\to b)\lor(c\not\to d)\lor(a\not\to d)\lor(b\not\to d)$, first use conditional equivalence to express the statement with only $\{\lor,\land,\neg\}$, then just try to apply Distributive law, see what would you get.

**Answer:**

> \begin{align}&\neg(a\to b)\lor\neg(c\to d)\lor\neg(a\to d)\lor\neg(b\to d)\\\equiv&\neg(\neg a\lor b)\lor\neg(\neg c\lor d)\lor\neg(\neg a\lor d)\lor\neg(\neg b\lor d)\tag*{Conditional equiv}\\\equiv& (a\land\neg b)\lor(c\land\neg d)\lor(a\land\neg d)\lor(b\land\neg d)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\\equiv& (a\land\neg b)\lor(\neg d\land c)\lor(\neg d\land a)\lor(\neg d\land b)\tag*{Commutative law}\\\equiv& (a\land\neg b)\lor(\neg d\land(c\lor a\lor b))\tag*{Distributive law}\\\equiv& ((a\land\neg b)\lor\neg d)\land(c\lor a\lor b)\tag*{Associative law}\\\equiv& (a\lor\neg d)\land(\neg b\lor\neg d)\land(c\lor a\lor b)\tag*{Distributive law}\\\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. :)